# Measuring time in microseconds on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, time

I’m trying to get system time in microseconds to measure time between two events. I need to measure at minimum to 1/10th of a millisecond.

I know of `NSDate` and `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`, but both only do milliseconds. Does anyone know of a way I can do this?

Comment: It has to be 1/10 of a millisecond at worst.  Why does subtracting 2 from 1 help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` calls `gettimeofday`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-855.11/CFDate.c), which has microsecond resolution.

`NSDate` is simply a wrapper around a `CFAbsoluteTime`, so it also has microsecond resolution.

Why do you think they only have millisecond resolution?

Comment: As when I change my date formatter to SSSSSS from SSS the last three digits are just filled with 0's.

Comment: What is the output of `NSLog(@"%.6f", CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent())`?  Does it end with `000`?

Comment: You are right - this does work - got 6 non-zero digits at the end :)

Answer (score 2):

See `mach_absolute_time`. It has granularity down to nanoseconds.

http://shiftedbits.org/2008/10/01/mach_absolute_time-on-the-iphone/